# How can I insert a single line of a text file in my HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I have an HTML page that I want to insert text from a text-only log file.

I can insert the text I need with the HTML object tag, but I get way more text than I need. Ideally, I'd just like the first line of this text file to be returned.

I need to do this without adding any libraries (jQuery), and no PHP or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have the file as a string you can do

```
myfile.split("\n")[0]
```

that gives you the first row

Answer (score 0):

What about putting it into a div only one line high and with overflow hidden?